# Macroscopic dimension of a brane

Tags: string-theory, branes

I'm reading Witten's [Solutions Of Four-Dimensional Field Theories Via M Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9703166), where it is discussed a configuration of threebranes stretched between fivebranes. My questions are: how can I understand the claim that if a dimension is finite in extent along the brane (in this case the direction along the stretching ending in the fivebranes) this dimension is macroscopically zero?

Is there a definition of macroscopic dimension independently of this? From this I would understand then that the macroscopic dimension of the brane is 3 instead of 4.